# Angular2 rc5: No provider for Http

Tags: angular, angular2-http

I'm trying to port an angular 2 application to RC5, but I have a problem: I cannot setup the application correctly via modules.

There's a service named CustomersService that retrieves customers data via Http. I've create an App Module that imports HttpModule and provides CustomersService. In another module, named HomeModule, there's a component that uses that service. When the application starts I see the following error on the console:

```js
EXCEPTION: Error in ./HomeComponent class HomeComponent_Host - inline template:0:0
ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: No provider for Http!
```

I have no idea why this is happening...

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Thank you.

---

Here are the files:

**app.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';

import { MdSidenavModule } from '@angular2-material/sidenav';
import { MdListModule } from '@angular2-material/list';
import { MdIconModule } from '@angular2-material/icon';
import { MdToolbarModule } from '@angular2-material/toolbar';
import { MdButtonModule } from '@angular2-material/button';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { routing } from './app.routing';
import { CustomersService } from './shared/rest_services/customers.service';

import { HomeModule } from './home/home.module';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [AppComponent],
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        HttpModule,

        // material design
        MdSidenavModule,
        MdListModule,
        MdIconModule,
        MdToolbarModule,
        MdButtonModule,

        routing,
        // SharedModule.foorRoot(),
        HomeModule
    ],
    providers: [
        CustomersService, Http
    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {

}
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { CustomersService } from './shared/rest_services/customers.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: 'app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {
  views = [ {title: 'Home', icon: 'home', path: 'home' } ];

  constructor() {

  }
}
```

**customers.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/Http';

@Injectable()
export class CustomersService {

  private static _base = 'http://...';

  constructor(private _http: Http) {

  }

  getAll() {
    return this._http.get(CustomersService._base + "/customers.json");
  }
}
```

**home.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { routing }       from './home.routing';
import { HomeComponent } from './home.component';

@NgModule({
    imports: [ routing ],
    declarations: [
        HomeComponent
    ],
    exports: [
        HomeComponent
    ]
})
export class HomeModule {

}
```

**home.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { CustomersService } from '../shared/rest_services/customers.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['home.component.scss']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private _customers: CustomersService) {
    this._customers.getAll().subscribe((data) => {
      console.log(data);
    });
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38969086/angular-2-rc5-no-provider-for-router maybe this one can help you.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I don't think that you need to specify something regarding Http in the `providers` attribute of your module. This is done when including the `HttpModule` in the `imports` attribute.

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [AppComponent],
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        HttpModule,

        // material design
        MdSidenavModule,
        MdListModule,
        MdIconModule,
        MdToolbarModule,
        MdButtonModule,

        routing,
        // SharedModule.foorRoot(),
        HomeModule
    ],
    providers: [
        CustomersService // <-----
    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {

}
```

The `HttpModule` configures the related providers for HTTP. See https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/modules/%40angular/http/http.ts#L354

Otherwise, perhaps it's a typo:

```
import { Http } from '@angular/Http';
```

instead of

```
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
```

Comment: Than you! Your a savior :)

Answer (score 1):

import http, then declare constructor having parameter of type Http,
like below

```
import {Http} from "@angular/http";

@Component({......})
export class CompName
{
   ......
constructor(private http: Http)
{
   ....
}

   .....
}
```