# Angular 2 RC5 : No provider for Router

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, routes

I am facing an issue using the new Angular 2 RC5 router (router version is RC1).

Here is the log I get from the dev console:

```
EXCEPTION: Error in /templates/app.component.html:2:0
ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: No provider for Router!
```

Here is what my app.modules.ts looks like:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { AppComponent }   from './components/app.component';
import { routing } from './app.routes';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [AppComponent],
    imports:      [BrowserModule, RouterModule, FormsModule, HttpModule, routing],
    bootstrap:    [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Here is my boot.ts file:

```
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

My app.routes.ts file...

```
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

// Components
import { HomeComponent } from './components/home.component';

const routes: Routes = [
    // Root
    { path: '/', name: 'Home', component: HomeComponent, useAsDefault: true},
];

// - Updated Export
export const routing = RouterModule.forRoot(routes);
```

...and my app.component.ts file:

```
import { Component, ViewContainerRef } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'app',
    templateUrl: '/templates/app.component.html'
})

export class AppComponent {
    viewContainerRef: any;

    public constructor(viewContainerRef:ViewContainerRef) {
        // You need this small hack in order to catch application root view container ref
        this.viewContainerRef = viewContainerRef;
    }
}
```

Is there something I am missing here?

Comment: "useAsDefault" is not a valid property anymore. I would also remove the '/' on the path property and add <base href='/' /> to your index.html file.

Comment: The Routes "name" also needs to be removed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Inside app.routes.ts file:

Add this import state

```
import { ModuleWithProviders } from '@angular/core';
```

Than

```
export const routing: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot(routes);
```

This should work.

Comment: Hey @EmmanuelScarabin Adding ModuleWithProviders did not fix for me. I have 'No provider for Router!' Error as soon as I add <router-outlet></router-outlet> tag in the app.component.html

Comment: @SudarP you should also check if you are not using "router-deprecated" in any of your components. That was the second reason causing this issue for me.